# How to leave me behind

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> If you wish to leave, then there's no doubt
>   first you must look for the way out.
>   Then with open eyes you must stare;
>   just look down to meet my glare.
>
> To remember this ordeal,
>   to take my thoughts and make them real,
>   then at the bottom, beside my eyes,
>   tell me where the treasure lies.
>
> If you'd rather forget your strife
>   and quietly, quickly end my life
>   get in line, but do not pout,
>   Instead you must scream and shout.
>
> Either way you're in the clear,
>   but there's one thing you must do from here:
>   say no more, come back inside,
>   and I'll let you off this crazy ride!

**What is this poem describing?**

Comment: Nice poem. But what's the question?

Comment: I guess the question is "How to leave me behind"

Comment: The goal is to figure out what is being described by the poem.

Comment: Ah, then it's too easy! It's obviously referring to the all-too-common situation of a microscope technician being abducted onto a rollercoaster to look at a miniature treasure map, only to find that the map is a fake, causing everyone much existential angst and the technician threatening to jump out of the rollercoaster along with the map because he's scared he'll be killed if he tells them it's a fake.

Comment: The treasury part gives me headaches.

Comment: @Hackiisan Incidentally, do you know any microscope technicians? And can you give me their address? And their schedule so I can know when to ambush them?

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I'm not surprised my poem is giving people headaches. English was my worst subject in high school.

Comment: I had a partial answer, Anonymity. Unfortunately it didn't hold up for enough of the poem for me to think it's the right answer. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: I don't know why this post has come up in my feed to haunt me, the asker was last seen in 2015.  Hard to get invested in a puzzle that will never have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this might sound crazy but my guess is

> Footwear

If you wish to leave, then there's no doubt
first you must look for the way out.

> Obviously the door

Then with open eyes you must stare;
just look down to meet my glare.

> I always wear shoes/sneakers/sandals while standing so I have to "look down" to see it.

To remember this ordeal,
to take my thoughts and make them real,
then at the bottom, beside my eyes,
tell me where the treasure lies.

> Fasten the Strap of the footwear. Eyes are the Lace holes, while I am reading "treasure lies" as "foot rests".

If you'd rather forget your strife
and quietly, quickly end my life
get in line, but do not pout,
Instead you must scream and shout.

> If it is uncomfortable (new ones sometimes are) instead of removing it, just "cry" in pain

Either way you're in the clear,
but there's one thing you must do from here:
say no more, come back inside,
and I'll let you off this crazy ride!

> Come back home or to a place and remove them after their use is over.

Comment: This was a really interesting answer, but it's not what I had in mind. I do treasure my feet though!

Comment: @RobF Thank you. Will try further to find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Tears

If you wish to leave, then there's no doubt
first you must look for the way out.

> If you wish you can cry But first you have a reason for it

Then with open eyes you must stare;
just look down to meet my glare.

> You can see it with your open tearful eyes,
>  You can meet it looking down

To remember this ordeal,
to take my thoughts and make them real,

> Our thoughts or feeling can look real when we're crying

then at the bottom, beside my eyes,
tell me where the treasure lies.

> And tears are almost alway a true treasure

If you'd rather forget your strife
and quietly, quickly end my life

> But if you still don't want to show it anyone else 
>  you can quickly swipe it out and end it's life

get in line, but do not pout,
Instead you must scream and shout.

> Instead of scream or shout just silently cry and roll it out

Either way you're in the clear,
but there's one thing you must do from here:
say no more, come back inside,
and I'll let you off this crazy ride!

> If you already cried a lot,
>  just say it to no more
>  if possible, come back inside or
>  Leave me behind all the sorrow

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about:

> The earth

*If you wish to leave, then there's no doubt
first you must look for the way out.
Then with open eyes you must stare;
just look down to meet my glare.*

> We walk on the earth so if you look down you'll see the earth

*To remember this ordeal,
to take my thoughts and make them real,
then at the bottom, beside my eyes,
tell me where the treasure lies.*

> Mineral resources are sometimes referred to as treasures

*If you'd rather forget your strife
and quietly, quickly end my life
get in line, but do not pout,
Instead you must scream and shout.*

This one got me struggling

> It might be a reference to the environmental damage we are doing and that we should scream and shout to wake the people up

*Either way you're in the clear,
but there's one thing you must do from here:
say no more, come back inside,
and I'll let you off this crazy ride!*

> When we die, we go back into earth by decomposing, and since we are dead we are off the ride.

Answer (score 0):

Is it?

> [Devil's snare](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Devil%27s_Snare), from the harry potter series

*If you wish to leave, then there's no doubt
first you must look for the way out.
Then with open eyes you must stare;
just look down to meet my glare.*

> You will be searching (looking) for a way out, with devil's snare the only way out is by going down. Devil's snare is also subdued by light so looking down (away) from the glare will let you free.

*To remember this ordeal,
to take my thoughts and make them real,
then at the bottom, beside my eyes,
tell me where the treasure lies.*

> Think really hard and at the bottom, you will find your metaphorical treasure containing freedom.

*If you'd rather forget your strife
and quietly, quickly end my life
get in line, but do not pout,
Instead you must scream and shout.*

> Many wish to escape devil's snare and would want to quickly kill the plant. Instead of trying to kill the plant (end his life) you must forget your current strife and scream and shout the required spell to escape.

*Either way you're in the clear,
but there's one thing you must do from here:
say no more, come back inside,
and I'll let you off this crazy ride*!

> The other way of getting out is by relaxing and surrendering to the plant completely, the plant will pull you down and as already stated, that's where the treasure lies.